# How to use variable of program class to another class?

Tags: c#, telnet

I need to use the following string variable of program class to TelnetConnection class,I do all possible ways but not worked , please give me sugessions. 
Thank you.

**program class**

```
 class Program
 {      
    static void main()
    {
     string s = telnet.Login("some credentials");
    }
 }
```

**TelnetConnection class**

```
 class TelnetConnection
 {
      public string Login(string Username, string Password, int LoginTimeOutMs)
        {

            int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
            TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;

            WriteLine(Username);

            s += Read();

            WriteLine(Password);

            s += Read();
            TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
            return s;
        }
  }
```

Comment: please further clarify the question and post the TelnetInterface (class?).

Comment: You need to instantiate an object of type "TelnetConnection" or make the method "Login" static to be able to use it in "Program.main()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
public class TelnetConnection
{
  public string Login(string Username, string Password, int LoginTimeOutMs)
  {
        string retVal = "";

        int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
        TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;

        WriteLine(Username);

        retVal += Read();

        WriteLine(Password);

        retVal  += Read();
        TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
        return retVal ;
    }
 }
```

In Program:

```
class Program
{      
    static void main()
    {
         var telnet = new TelnetConnection();
         string s = telnet.Login("some username", "some password", 123);
    }
 }
```

But it seems there is some code missing in your example, especially the implementation of the `Read` method.

If you want to alter the program's string variable, you can pass it to the method with the `ref` keyword:

```
public class TelnetConnection
{
  public string Login(string Username, 
                      string Password, int LoginTimeOutMs, ref string retVal)
  {
        //omitted
        retVal += Read();

        WriteLine(Password);

        retVal  += Read();
        TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
        return retVal ;
    }
 }
```

In Program:

```
class Program
{      
    static void main()
    {
         var telnet = new TelnetConnection();
         string s = ""; 
         telnet.Login("some username", "some password", 123, ref s);
         //s is altered here
    }
 }
```